# MSSQL join a local table with a remoted linked server function table

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures, linked-server

I would like to join a local table with a table with return by a remote link server function.

This is how I execute the remote link server function.

```
exec linkedServer.DB.dbo.sp_executesql N'SELECT *  FROM FunctionA(''parameter'')'
```

I would like to join to local table as something like this:

```
select * from LocalTable a 
left join 
    (exec linkedServer.DB.dbo.sp_executesql 
          N'SELECT * FROM FunctionA(''parameter'')') as b 
on a.key = b.key
```

How can I do this? Do I need a temp table to do this?

Comment: I don't think the sp_executesql is needed ... you could also just "SELECT * FROM linkedServer.DB.dbo.FunctionA('parameter')" ... this could be joined with a local table ...

Comment: Try  "SELECT * FROM linkedServer.DB.dbo.FunctionA('parameter')". It give me error Remote table-valued function calls are not allowed. Then, I try add the SELECT * FROM linkedServer.DB.dbo.FunctionA('parameter') (nolock) , it give "linkedServer.DB.dbo.FunctionA is not a recognized function name."

Comment: Try "SELECT * FROM linkedServer.DB.dbo.FunctionA('parameter') WITH (NOLOCK)"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use `OPENQUERY`, and for making join need to add function column names to with part like `;WITH b(col1, col2, ...)`

```
;WITH b(key) AS (
    SELECT * FROM OPENQUERY (linkedServer, N'SELECT * FROM DB.dbo.FunctionA(''parameter'')')
)
SELECT * FROM LocalTable a
    LEFT JOIN b on a.key = b.key
```

or you can make without with

```
SELECT * FROM LocalTable a
    LEFT JOIN (SELECT * FROM OPENQUERY (linkedServer, N'SELECT * FROM DB.dbo.FunctionA(''parameter'')'))b(key) 
        on a.key = b.key
```

Comment: You can also save the output of a function to #temp table first and then join this #temp table.